# wait for user action to continue code execution

Tags: python, pyside

Here is my code:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *

class window_A(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window_A, self).__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout() # Create horisontal layout
        self.setLayout(layout) # Use horisontal layout to place widgets in window
        self.resize(300,50) # resize window

        self.button_A = QPushButton('PRESS')
        self.button_A.clicked.connect(self.func)
        self.button_A.clicked.connect(self.close)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_A)

    def func(self):
        print 'A'


app = QApplication([])

print 'BEFORE'
widget = window_A()
widget.show()
print 'AFTER'

app.exec_()
```

How can I hold the execution of code after showing the window until the user will press the button? E.g. print 'AFTER' only after button pressed and window closed.

Answer (score 2):

In this case to prevent synchronous execution from continuing you can use a QEventLoop, and to notify if the window is closed you can implement a signal that is emitted in closeEvent:

```py
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class Window_A(QtGui.QWidget):
    closed = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window_A, self).__init__()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.resize(300, 50)

        self.button_A = QtGui.QPushButton("PRESS")
        self.button_A.clicked.connect(self.func)
        self.button_A.clicked.connect(self.close)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_A)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def func(self):
        print("A")

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        super(Window_A, self).closeEvent(event)
        self.closed.emit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    print("BEFORE")
    widget = Window_A()
    widget.show()
    loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
    widget.closed.connect(loop.quit)
    loop.exec_()
    print("AFTER")
```

Comment: Thanks, bro!
But this is not what I am looking for, cos in the real scenario I don't have 
`app = QApplication([])` and `app.exec_()` calls, the script is running in another application. 

So I need to handle the logic as I describe, run window and wait for user response...

Something like:

`W = Window_A()

if W.show():
   do my next code
    `

Comment: @kiryha Unfortunately you can not do what you want :-( . Qt has a structure that can not be modified since it does not have an eventloop that serves to be notified of events of the OS and other components. So what you should do is modify your other code so that it adapts to the GUI.

Comment: @kiryha Your problem is design, you have to learn to manage the business logic with the GUI. Generally, when you start programming, the structured programming paradigm is used a lot (that is, executing line by line), but Qt is an asynchronous library that uses event-oriented programming where actions are done when necessary (for example, through signals , QEvents, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution! Need to change `QWidget` to `QDialog` and `show` to `exec_()`:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *

class window_A(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window_A, self).__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout() # Create horisontal layout
        self.setLayout(layout) # Use horisontal layout to place widgets in window
        self.resize(300,50) # resize window

        self.button_A = QPushButton('PRESS')
        self.button_A.clicked.connect(self.func)
        self.button_A.clicked.connect(self.close)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_A)

    def func(self):
        print 'A'
        self.done(256)


app = QApplication([])
print 'BEFORE'
widget = window_A()
if widget.exec_() == 256:
    print 'AFTER'
app.exec_()
```